# How do I access my rooted android phone's \data\data folder using android java app?

Tags: android

I am having rooted HTC Explorer A310e and want's to access its \data\data directory without using superuser.apk. Is there any solution for it using Android Java application.

Thanks !

Comment: Are you trying to develop an app for this or you need an app that does this?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what version of the `su` (or any other [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) binaries) you installed when rooting. The "standard" `su` tool installed when rooting Android requires Superuser.apk in order to provide user authorization for performing root activities, but you could install one that does not.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but from where do I get setuid binary which do not ask for authorization.

Comment: If you search for the source to `su` it is readily available. I think the Android emulator may actually have an `su` binary (that does not use superuser.apk) built into it, which you could extract and place on your device.

Answer (score -1):

```
 File f = new File("/data/data/your.namespace/yourfile.ext");
```

Comment: The question is specific to using root permission to access files which you have no non-root permission to access. Your answer has nothing to do with that.